# How to do Outlook HTML email signature mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook

I did outlook HTML signature and it's look good and work good, but on mobile it's look pretty big. If it possible to do my signature responsive?
My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Signature</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Signature4.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="880" height="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/Signature4_01.png" width="880" height="263" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="matt.yesmaniski@themenorahgroup.com">
                <img src="images/email.png" width="301" height="37" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Signature4_03.png" width="58" height="37" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Imagine-Built-Homes/109522549076128" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/facebook.png" width="28" height="37" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Signature4_05.png" width="1" height="37" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/ImagineBltHomes" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/twitter.png" width="28" height="37" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Signature4_07.png" width="464" height="37" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try replacing all your fixed widths with percentages, that should adjust to fit the device. For example, make table width 100% instead of 880 etc

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about it.